# I get the error when trying to create spark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("local")
.appName("pyspark_uygulama") \
    .getOrCreate()
    
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc
```

---

```
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4820/1639526332.py", line 7
.appName("pyspark_uygulama") \
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: indentation is critical in Python, those lines two spaces right

Comment: @ItayB Intendation isn't the problem. The line continuation char is missing after `.master()`

Answer (score 1):

You miss the `\` after the `.master("local")`. There should also be no spaces before `\`, that is

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
  .master("local")\
  .appName("pyspark_uygulama")\
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: "There should also be no spaces before \ " - This is NOT true. There can be spaces.